# Extending or customizing XM Cloud - Sitecore Pages to support droplink editing

Tags: sxa, jss, xm-cloud, sxa-jss

Is there a way to extend or customize Sitecore Pages to allow editing `droplink` or `droptree` in the `side panel` for `XM cloud`, similar to how we can edit the currently supported fields here https://doc.sitecore.com/xmc/en/users/xm-cloud/configuring-components.html?

Answer (score 0):

As this has gone unanswered, our workaround is to add the field as a rendering parameter with `droplist` type. This means we can only get the referenced item's `item name` as value and use this as necessary in our front-end component.

The limitation of course is we cannot use field values within the referenced item.

Another workaround is to add the field in the page level. As the `Content` tab in `Pages` and the `Content Manager` supports `droplink` and `droptree` fields.